# Get max key of dictionary based on ratio key:value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is my dictionary:

`inventory = {60: 20, 100: 50, 120: 30}`

Keys are total cost of goods [$] and values are available weight [lb].

I need to find a way to get key based on the highest cost per pound.

I have already tried using:

`most_expensive = max(inventory, key={fucntion that calculates the ratio})`

But cannot guess the pythonic way to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. By using the `key` argument you can calculate the ratio. The thing you are missing is that you want to compare the key and values, therefore you can use the `inventory.items()`.

The code would be:

```
max(inventory.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]/x[1])
```

Which will result in the following if I use your values:

```
(120, 30)
```

In order to get only the key, you have to get the first element of the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Thymen, this was the pythonic answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key of the maximum ratio directly with a key function that takes a key and returns the ratio:

```
max(inventory, key=lambda k: k / inventory[k])
```

This returns, given your sample input:

```
120
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following would be considered pretty pythonic :)

`max([key/value for key, value in inventory.items()])`

Comment: Thanks @ViggoTW for your answer. I have chosen answer from Thymen as is it was the pythonic way I was looking for.